# Problema IIS 7 (alto consumo de CPU)

Tags: iis

Tenho um servidor com aplicações em Aspnet em rodando IIS 7.

Sempre funcionou normalmente. Mas, desde ontem a CPU esta utilizando sempre 100% nos horários com mais acessos, ocasionando indisponibilidade em vários sites e perda de performance.

Já tentei limitar o tamanho do pool em memória e limitar o processamento dos pools, já reiniciei o servidor e o IIS várias vezes, mas sempre volta o problema.

Alguém tem alguma ideia sobre o que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Está claro que seu servidor não está a escalar o suficientemente bem para a demanda que deveria atender. A recomendação é conseguir mais recursos, i.e.: pense em utilizar mais máquinas, ou melhorar o hardware da máquina atual.

Comment: Isso eu percebi, mas eu estou buscando uma solução que possa ser aplicada no momento, não tem como eu alocar mais recursos nesse servidor. Alguém mais tem uma sugestão?

Comment: Alocar mais recursos == comprar um processador mais potente.

Answer (score 1):

**Pode ser problema em alguma aplicação**, se uma aplicação faz uso incorreto de memória ou de outros recursos do sistema, em geral, os efeitos aparecem no IIS.

Para verificar se é problema em alguma aplicação você pode utilizar ferramentas que irão te ajudar a diagnosticar qual o *Work Process*/processo de trabalho de qual aplicação específica que está consumindo a CPU do servidor e verificar se é algum problema pontual (problema em uma página X, em um loop, etc).

Para verificar o consumo por aplicação:
1. Abra o IIS
2. Selecione o servidor/raiz
3. Clique em Worker Processes

[image: Abrindo Worker Processes IIS]

Identifique a aplicação com maior consumo de CPU para analise

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Esse link](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool) possui alguns passos para ajudar a diagnosticar e solucionar esses problemas.